# how to run after compiling thru gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I am using the java plugin in my build.gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'java' 

repositories { 
   mavenCentral() 
} 

dependencies {
    compile 'xyz:xyz:4.11'
}

sourceSets {
    test {
        java {
            srcDir 'agent'
        }
    }
}
```

I am generating the .class files by doing

```
$ gradle compileJava
```

Now that the .class files have been generated in build/, how do I run my code? One of the class files contains the main. I want to do something like this from a gradle task:

```
CLASSPATH=./mysql-connector-java-commercial-5.1.13-bin.jar:. $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=10000 Collector arg1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on ghik's answer, I add these to my gradle.build script:

```
apply plugin:'application'

....

dependencies {
    ....
    runtime  'mysql:mysql-connector-java-commercial:5.1.13'
}

mainClassName = "Collector"

run {
    args 'arg1'
    jvmArgs '-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=10000'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at [Gradle Application Plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html).

With it, you will be able to run your application just using a `run` task.